# How to make Swagger2 use ObjectMapper's PropertyNamingStrategy (e.g. SNAKE_CASE)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-2.0

I have a configuration class that returns a custom `ObjectMapper` instance:

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        return new ObjectMapper()
           .setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE);
    }
}
```

and I have a Swagger2 configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build();
    }
}
```

I want the generated api docs (/v2/api-docs) to contain snake case names. Unfortunately they contain camel case names.

Comment: ok, i have found the cause - Spring Data REST, which adds new HttpMessageConverter, not using my ObjectMapper. Another issue is why Swagger is using the ObjectMapper from the converters, not directly from the Spring context.